# Call method in a class which called the current class

Tags: python, oop

How could I call the method 'z'? Which is he best way for this?
And to an object?

File test1.py:

```
from test2 import Test2

class Test1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def a(self):
        print("Running a of Test1")
        test_instance2 = Test2()
    def z(self):
        print("Running z of Test1")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_instance = Test1()
    test_instance.a()
```

File test2.py:

```
class Test2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b()
    def b(self):
        print('Running b of Test2')
        print('Here I want to call method z of Test1') # < How call z in Test1?
```

Run as:

```
python test1.py
```

Thanks in advance! :) I'm so sorry the elementary question :$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will *have* to pass in a reference to the `Test1` instance:

```
class Test1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def a(self):
        print("Running a of Test1")
        test_instance2 = Test2(self)
    def z(self):
        print("Running z of Test1")

class Test2:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.b(a)
    def b(self, a):
        print('Running b of Test2')
        a.z()
```

You could store the `a` reference on the `Test2` instance too:

```
class Test2:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        self.b()
    def b(self, a):
        print('Running b of Test2')
        self.a.z()
```